# replace or append text using jquery after loading the page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have string in the  need to replace or append text after loading the page. please see the html code

```
<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 width='100%' class='ms-informationbar'
    style='margin-bottom: 5px;' border=0>
   <tr>
    <td width=10 valign=center 
       style='padding: 4px'><img src='/_layouts/images/exclaim.gif' alt='' />
    </td>
    <td>Items on this list require content approval. Your submission will not
       appear in public views until approved by someone with proper rights. 
       <a href=javascript:HelpWindowKey("ContentApproval")>More information on 
       content approval.</a>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0  
       width=100% class='ms-informationbar' style='margin-bottom: 5px;' border=0>
   </table>
```

Now 
I have to replace text

```
  Items on this list require content approval. Your submission will not
       appear in public views until approved by someone with proper rights. 
       <a href=javascript:HelpWindowKey("ContentApproval")>More information on 
       content approval.</a>**
```

with

```
Items on this list require content approval. Your submission will not
  appear in public views until approved by someone with proper rights. 
  <a href=javascript:HelpWindowKey("ContentApproval")>More information on 
   content approval.</a> The editing session will timeout in 40 minutes
```

How can we do this jQuery?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".ms-informationbar tr td").eq(1).html('Items on this list require content approval. Your submission will not
  appear in public views until approved by someone with proper rights. 
  <a href=javascript:HelpWindowKey("ContentApproval")>More information on 
   content approval.</a> The editing session will timeout in 40 minutes');

});
```

This will select the second td which is found in a tr in an element with the class `.ms-informationbar` and replace its' content with the html between the quotes.

Comment: How this 'The editing session will timeout in 40 minutes' will be in new line?

Comment: @James123 just add a <br> or put it in a separate <div> or <p> (they are by default block elements, so they start a new line)

Comment: @James123 It's worth noting that any change to your mark-up concerning the order of your tds will essentially break the code above, so you're better off adding an ID or a class to the desired td.

Comment: hard coding the text in a javascript function is bad practice. If this text needs to be updated, chances are the function will not be updated at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this:

first, put a class or id in the TD element, so you can reference it more easily:

```
<td class="ApprovalNotice">Items on this list require content approval. Your submission will not
       appear in public views until approved by someone with proper rights. 
       <a href=javascript:HelpWindowKey("ContentApproval")>More information on 
       content approval.</a>
    </td>
```

Now you could do something like:

```
origHtml = $('.ApprovalNotice').html();
$('.ApprovalNotice').html(origHtml + yourText);
```

Or you could do something simpler:

```
<td class="ApprovalNotice">Items on this list require content approval. Your submission will not
           appear in public views until approved by someone with proper rights. 
           <a href=javascript:HelpWindowKey("ContentApproval")>More information on 
           content approval.</a><span class="timeout" style="display:none;">your text goes here</span>        </td>
```

and then

```
$('.timeout').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ID` to the `TD` you want to change.

`<td id="infoText">...</td>`

Then you can change the contents like this

`$('#infoText').html('New Text')`

http://jsfiddle.net/H5Vh8/